# can a JLabel show overflow (x or y or both)?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jlabel

So in css you can set overflow on a div, for eg, and force it to show any overflowing elements appended to it. Can you do that with swing?

```
JLabel outside=new JLabel();
outside.setBounds(100,100,400,400);
JLabel inside=new JLabel();
inside.setBounds(0,0,500,400);
outside.add(inside); // show the cropped parts?
```

I'm aware I've omitted a bucket load of other code. This is more just theory. I did google 'JLabel overflow' as well as 'Swing Component overflow' but couldn't find anything concrete.

If there's no simple answer, just type 'No' and I'll leave it alone.

Thanks

Comment: In any meaningful way, no, I can't think of a way

Comment: I hope I understood it in the right sense, that you wanted to place a JLabel on top of another. If Yes, then you can do that, simply you have to set the Layout for the JLabel in that case. Here is one [quick example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10245045/1057230) for  you for further help ask anything that you couldn't understand. Though actually how you intend to use this, will determine how good is this approach :-)

Comment: still wasting everybody's time (as in http://stackoverflow.com/q/12541673/203657) ... again: learn how layout works in swing.

Comment: @kleopatra Even while I read javadocs, I get ideas and questions pop into my head. When I can't get a definite answer from oracle's pages, I search elsewhere. And in case you didn't notice, I only asked for a simple answer. I wasn't asking for someone to write my program for me, do my homework or my job, like most of the questions around here.